# Troubleshooting assembly dependency chain issues on TeamCity

Tags: c#, testing, dependencies, continuous-integration, teamcity

We have a .NET solution that I'm trying to get to run in our new CI environment, TeamCity.

The solution builds and runs, and all unit tests run (not all pass, but that's a different story) on our dev machines.

It builds properly on the CI server as well, but when running the MSTest configuration, it fails, giving a message like:

```
Unable to load the test container '[one of my test assemblies]' or one of its dependencies.  Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '[one of my assemblies]' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Well, my assembly is built and available, so that's unlikely.  On my local dev machine, I can get more detail with procmon or the like to see where the dependency chain is broken, but I'm not sure how I can do that against a remote server.

How can I find out what my CI server is missing to do its job?  Is there some logging I can enable or something?

Comment: IMHO the quickest way to solve this is to RDP to the CI machine using the account that TC runs under and try and run the build from where TC checked out the code

Comment: @SamHolder It works from there if I invoke it manually :(

Comment: Bugger. Next thing I would do is to run the team City build with proc mon running. But you'll end up with a big trace to analyse.

Comment: Sorry does Ms test run from the command line on the build server Ok? Or just the build?

Comment: @SamHolder honestly I cannot figure out how to run it properly from the command line (I have multiple test projects)... but when specifying the  target that blows up in TC, it does not throw an exception... it also does not run any tests.  I don't know if that's good or bad.

Comment: Either get it running from the command line or run proc mon whilst tc is running the tests. Proc Mon will at least show the actual error from tc's point of view

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the working directory is wrong when you are attempting to run tests.

Is your Build and Unit Tests steps in the same "Build Configuration"?